# Showing sum of multiple columns in datatables

Tags: datatable

I am trying get the sum of multiple columns in my datatables. I am following the following link. https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html
This datatables link explanation is really good in case of getting the sum of just one column, but my use case is to print multiple column sum (Even the sum of all the string values, for example all the users).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I found the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034073/sum-on-1-columns-in-datatables-footer-using-footer-callback)